# Perl Morgan and a String?

Tags: string, algorithm, perl

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/morgan-and-a-string/copy-from/15097578) problem on hackerrank:

So the problem is:

*Jack and Daniel are friends. Both of them like letters, especially upper-case ones. 
They are cutting upper-case letters from newspapers, and each one of them has their collection of letters stored in separate stacks. 
One beautiful day, Morgan visited Jack and Daniel. He saw their collections. Morgan wondered what is the lexicographically minimal string, made of that two collections. He can take a letter from a collection when it is on the top of the stack.
Also, Morgan wants to use all the letters in the boys' collections.*

This is my attempt in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
chomp(my $n=<>);
while($n>0){
    chomp(my $string1=<>);
    chomp(my $string2=<>);
    lexi($string1,$string2);
    $n--;
}
sub lexi{
   my($str1,$str2)=@_;
   my @str1=split(//,$str1);
   my @str2=split(//,$str2);
   my $final_string="";

   while(@str2 && @str1){
       my $st2=$str2[0];
       my $st1=$str1[0];
       if($st1 le $st2){
         $final_string.=$st1;
         shift @str1;
       }
       else{
          $final_string.=$st2;
          shift @str2;
       }
  }
  if(@str1){
       $final_string=$final_string.join('',@str1);
  }
  else{
       $final_string=$final_string.join('',@str2);
  }
  print $final_string,"\n";
}
```

**Sample Input:**

```
2
JACK
DANIEL
ABACABA
ABACABA
```

The first line contains the number of test cases, T. 
Every next two lines have such format: the first line contains string A, and the second line contains string B.

**Sample Output:**

```
DAJACKNIEL
AABABACABACABA
```

But for *Sample test-case* it is giving *right results* while it is giving *wrong results* for *other test-cases*. One case for which it gives an incorrect result is

```
1
AABAC
AACAB
```

It outputs `AAAABACCAB` instead of `AAAABACABC`.

I don't know what is wrong with the algorithm and why it is failing with other test cases?

**Update:**

As per @squeamishossifrage comments If I add

```
($str1,$str2)=sort{$a cmp $b}($str1,$str2);
```

The results become same irrespective of user-inputs but still the test-case fails.

Comment: It is preferable to include a summary of the thing you're trying to solve - otherwise your answer is reliant on that link, which is bad news if it ever disappears.

Comment: @Sobrique added summary and Input/Output.

Comment: I haven't got time to figure out what the problem is, but it's quite easy to find test cases that your code fails on. For example, the strings `AABAC` and `AACAB` give different results depending on the order in which they are presented.

Comment: I don't know Perl. Do you compare the entire remaining string or just the current character? You should definitely do the former.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage It fails when both characters from strings are equal and *It fails because it removes characters from different string depending on user input and I am not sure from which string I should remove the character if they are equal*

Comment: @ikegami testcases are too big to analyze it manually. anyways for  this it fails [input](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/2335/input01.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1447091929&Signature=Dk9yixAhZFMADlbkXQeEHe6u6YA%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) and [output](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/2335/output01.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1447091944&Signature=CQK12QdpUW6SoyP65JDTxXJszk8%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your handling of the equal characters. Take the following example:

```
ACBA
BCAB
```

When faced with two identical characters (`C` in my example), you naïvely chose the one from the first string, but that's not always correct. You need to look ahead to break ties. You may even need to look many characters ahead. In this case, next character after `C` of the second string is lower than the next character of the first string, so you should take the `C` from the second string first.

By leaving the strings as strings, a simple string comparison will compare as many characters as needed to determine which character to consume.

```
sub lexi {
   my ($str1, $str2) = @_;

   utf8::downgrade($str1);  # Makes sure length() will be fast
   utf8::downgrade($str2);  # since we only have ASCII letters.

   my $final_string = "";
   while (length($str2) && length($str1)) {
      $final_string .= substr($str1 le $str2 ? $str1 : $str2, 0, 1, '');
   }

   $final_string .= $str1;
   $final_string .= $str2;
   print $final_string, "\n";
}
```

Comment: check the update I am selecting `smaller string lexicographically` after sorting them.

Comment: Thank you very much @ikegami I got it Thanks a million times.

Comment: Actually in conditions we have limitation. "He can take a letter from a collection when it is on the top of the stack. " So Solution shouldn't use any CACHE. Otherwise we have wrong task setup!!! By using $str1 le $str2 you are comparing whole strings, not just last char, like in STACK

Comment: @Yevgen Kulik, That's intentional. Comparing just the <strike>last</strike>next char would be wrong. That's what the OP was doing, and that's why he wasn't getting the wrong result. You have to keeping comparing characters until one is different. I explained this in detail in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Too little rep to comment thus the answer:

What you need to do is to look ahead if the two characters match. You currently do a simple le match and in the case of

```
ZABB
ZAAA
```

You'll get ZABBZAA since the first match Z will be le Z. So what you need to do (a naive solution which most likely won't be very effective) is to keep looking as long as the strings/chars match so:

```
Z eq Z
ZA eq ZA
ZAB gt ZAA
```

and at that point will you know that the second string is the one you want to pop from for the first character.

**Edit**
You updated with sorting the strings, but like I wrote you still need to look ahead. The sorting will solve the two above strings but will fail with these two:

```
ZABAZA
ZAAAZB
ZAAAZBZABAZA
```

Because here the correct answer is ZAAAZABAZAZB and you can't find that will simply comparing character per character

Comment: `since the first match Z will be le Z.` may you please explain it more?

Comment: I can comment my own posts so sure: in your code you're having the two first characters and they are both Z. You're doing le (alpha equivalent of <=)  so it'll always pick the first of the two strings as the preferred one. However that's only the reason why you're getting different result for different order. The real problem is that you don't look forward. You need if ($str1 eq $str2) { continue comparing substrings until you see which path is shortest }, your current if/else isn't enough

Comment: Thank you @jon It took me a whole day to understand this.